# SharePoint 2010 - How to edit the default message "There are no items to show in this view of the list."

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to edit the default message *"There are no items to show in this view of the "listname" list. To add a new item, click "New"* in a simple (out of the box) way?

I would like to display a custom message if there are no items (due to the expiration of messages) shown.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. By default SharePoint uses XSLT template to render list view. You can find start point in this [topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/3c95b8ed-cb73-46fb-bc19-1d416d50a0ef).

Answer (score 2):

As a note to folks looking for a solution to this question for **Office 365 or SharePoint 2013**, you can edit the message using JS Link and CSR. For details and example code see this blog post: 
http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2015/jslink-csr-to-override-there-are-no-items-to-show-in-this-view/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)